# Stacking Order Maintenance in Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

Is there a way to keep consistent stacking order of widgets (particularly images) from within Tkinter?  For example, I may have two rectangles, two triangles, and a circle all at the same location on the canvas. The circle moves to wherever the mouse was last clicked, but I always want it to be drawn on top of rectangles and behind triangles. The default behavior is of course to place the last-drawn object at a given location on top.

I've only found the lift() and lower() methods to address stacking in Tkinter thus far. I could theoretically make some messy checks at every re-draw to see whether triangles exist at the destination and do some lift()/lower() for each shape there until things are the way I want, but it seems an absurd solution. I expected there to be a sort of "layer" variable on canvas objects so it would passively remember that items of layer 3 should always be behind those of layer 1.

I apologize if there is a simple method to solve my problem, but as of yet all my searching has been to no avail. I will be thankful for any input!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tag all triangles with "triangle", all rectangles with "rectangle" and all circles with "circle". You can then use the `lift` or `lower` method to raise or lower all triangles, circles or rectangles at once. It takes just a couple of statements and will happen in less than the blink of an eye even if you have thousands of items.

Since you asked about a built-in layer mechanism: tk has no such thing but it's really easy to add, all the tools are there. So, instead of sprinkling `lift` or `lower` commands everywhere, have all your drawing go through a special command that handles the layering for you.

For example, here is a an example of a command that accepts a layer number and makes sure everything it draws is on that layer:

```py
def add_to_layer(self, layer, command, coords, **kwargs):
    layer_tag = "layer %s" % layer
    if layer_tag not in self._layers: self._layers.append(layer_tag)
    tags = kwargs.setdefault("tags", [])
    tags.append(layer_tag)
    item_id = command(coords, **kwargs)
    self._adjust_layers()
    return item_id

def _adjust_layers(self):
    for layer in sorted(self._layers):
        self.canvas.lift(layer)
```

You would then call it like this:

```py
# draw a circle on layer 1:
self.add_to_layer(1, self.canvas.create_oval, (x0,y0,x1,y1), outline="red")
# draw a square on layer 2:
self.add_to_layer(2, self.canvas.create_rectangle, (x0,y0,x1,y1), fill="blue")
```

There are many other ways to accomplish the same thing, the above is just a quick and dirty example off the top of my head (and not guaranteed to be 100% correct, but I think it illustrates the point).

The basic idea is that all object creation goes through a single function which can adjust the stacking order each time an item is created. That way you only have to add those lift/lower commands in one place.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. I was hoping I wouldn't have to disperse those statements throughout my code, but it looks like there isn't a simpler way. I appreciate the help!

Comment: @Taugosz: I've updated my answer to show how you have everything you need to implement a layering system. There's nothing built-in but it only takes a tiny bit of imagination to implement your own layering.

Comment: I am embarrassed I didn't come up with such a solution earlier; I certainly did have the tools I needed. I am very grateful that you took the time to put together such complete code to illustrate your point.